# Send and receive UDP packets using c

Tags: c, sockets

Here I'm trying to send my formatted data to multiple servers and receive reply from them one by one. However , when I run the code, it only received the first one's reply, and stucked  at recvfrom(). Does anyone know why this happen and how to solve it?

```
for(int i=0;i<s->count;i++)
{
    int fromserver=0;
    recv[i]=malloc(2048);
    sendToserver(s->UDPserverID,udpFrame,s->neighbors[i]);
    while(1){
        fromserver=recvfrom(s->UDPserverID,recv[i],2048,MSG_WAITALL,(struct sockaddr*)&sender,&addr_size);
        if(fromserver!=0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    ask_back[i]=stringToFrame(recv[i]);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the structure of your program, but shouldn't you first send to all servers, and then wait for all answers? It seems you only send to one, then wait ad vitaem for answers?

Comment: If socket created with `O_NONBLOCK`, then you can loop on the `recvfrom` function to see status on each attempt.  Otherwise, until a message is seen it will block.

Comment: `MSG_WAITALL` has no effect on datagram sockets.

Comment: UDP is unreliable and both the data to and from the server can get lost. If this happens, you program will block indefinitely.

Comment: I was using sendToAll(), and a while loop count for the reply packets, but it didn't work.. I'm new to network programming, this is for a project to design a transport station network using TCP&UDP sockets, on localhost

Comment: cause it's running on localhost so packets shouldn't be lost I think..